# Preemption Priorities and Movement

Tags: anylogic

I’m trying to model a queue of ships that utilize a static resource which is a single dock (using flowcharts).
The queue has three types of agents A, B, and C which have priorities 1, 2, and 3 respectively (this means that ship C has priority in the queue to utilize the dock).
Now I need to model the following two behaviors related to preemption:

1. The task of unloading the ship (the dock’s task when seized) must preempt when ship C arrives BUT not when ship A or B arrives. This means that the priorities defined in the “Task priority” field are valid to define the queue order of attention but not for preemption. The priorities for preemption should be: Ship A and B with priority 1 and Ship C with priority 2.
   How can I separate the priorities “ratings” for the queue from the priorities used to determine preemption?

[shows the issue of having the same priority for queue and preemption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbwQw.png)

2. When the task preempt, I need to move the current ship that is using the dock, to a waiting area, and when the task that caused the preemptions ends, the ship that preempted, must return to where the static resource is (the dock) and resume its delay block. How can I do this?
   I tried using the outPreempted port of the Seize block to add a moveTo block to move the agent to the waiting area, but this port seems to work only when preemption causes to end the task (terminate serving option).
   The flowchart of the described queue I’m trying to model is shown on the image with some red lines trying to explain intuitively (but wrong) what I’m trying to do:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m607a.png)

Comment: I just solved point 2 with the "On task suspended" and "On task resumed" fields using agent.moveTo(...) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not separate the two? What you could do is put a **Queue** object before the **Seize** with A=1, B=2, C=3 ordering, then set the queue size of the **Seize** object to 0 and put the pre-emption priorities (A,B=1; C=2) into the **Seize** task priority field like you've done here.

**UPDATE**
Having looked it some more, it appears the queue size on **Seize** can not be zero. In this case, the implementation was done using a **Wait** block. [image: see here]

Additionally `on enter` action of the *seize* block contains following code:

```java
List<TestTwoSeizes_Demand> toFree = new ArrayList<>();

// there should be one agent in 'wait' and this will 
// mark it for removal
wait.forEach(waitingAgent -> {
    if (!waitingAgent.agent_type.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
        waitingAgent.preempted_by_C = true;
        toFree.add(waitingAgent);
    }
});

if (!toFree.isEmpty())
    toFree.forEach(a -> wait.free(a));
```

Also, the agent flowing through the process has 2 properties:

1. *agent_type* - string A, B or C
2. *preempted_by_C* - boolean, initially set to 'false'

So this is how it works:

1. *selectOutput* sorts agents so that "C" go to *seize* and A, B goe to *seize1*
2. *wait* is configured to exit on timeout so normally it acts like a delay
3. *seize* defines priority 3 and *seize1* defines priorities 1, 2 for A & B respectively, so "C" agents in *seize* will always come first
4. when a "C" agent appears it will kick out and A or B agent out of *wait*
5. *selectOutput1* checks if the *preempted_by_C* flag is not set, and if it is then the kicked out agent goes back into *seize1*, but it is possible to give them any behaviour

Hopefully this works. Not the cleanest solution, but it seems that it is not possible to do queueing-preemption priority separation using standard configuration options.

Comment: Hi. The size of the seize queues can't be set to 0.

Comment: Hi Artem P. Thank you very much for your answer!! I found an easier solution and was to create a function that sets the priority in the seize queue. This function evaluates where the static resource is busy or waiting for the next agent. If the resource is busy it sets the priority of ship C to 2 and A and B to 1 and when the dock is ready to receive the next agent in the queue is sets priority C=3, B=2, A=1. The key for this implementation was the function recalculatePriorities of the queue when exiting the release block.

Comment: Thank for sharing, that is an interesting approach! Also, I would recommend keeping C priority as 3 at all times because you're potentially creating a situation where a resourced seized by a C ship when it's priority was 2 is pre-empted by a C ship with priority 3.